# Automatically select a template for a child page with the same name as another

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

In a wordpress website I have this page structure:

```
/posts
/another-page/posts
```

Basically they are two different pages listing different posts, even though the name (posts) is the same. The two pages should use different templates. For the first "posts" page I just create a file called page-posts.php, and it's automatically chosen. How can make the same thing for the other "posts" page?

Is the only solution to create a template and manually select it from the dropdown in the admin page? Isn't there any way to change the slug withouth affecting the url?

Answer (score 1):

You can create two template files name page-{id}.php for each page. This would handle both pages for you.

[Template Hierarchy Page Section](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Page_display)

The IDs for each page will be unique. So when you select Edit from the WP-Admin area, look at the URL and you can find the ID.

```
/wp-admin/post.php?post=6163&action=edit
```

For this page, my page ID would **6163**. So the template name would page-**6163**.php.

Cheers

Comment: so there's no way at all to keep doing with slug?

Comment: would the templates be different if it was a parent page instead of a child page?

Answer (score 0):

You could try hooking to the page template action, checking for your custom url structure, and if it exists, outputting your custom template.

```
 add_filter( 'page_template', 'custom_page_template' );

 function custom_page_template( $page_template )  {
     $url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

     if ( false !== strpos( $url, '/another-page/posts' ) ) {
         $page_template = dirname(  __FILE__  ) . '/path_to_my_template.php';
     }

     return $page_template;
 }
```